# Reshape ordered array to table

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to convert an ordered list of data recordings into a tabular format, I've created an example input and output below. I could do this on the client quite easily but would prefer to do it on the server if possible; ideally using the aggregation framework but could be that map reduce is the only option.

I've used several pipeline stages to get the data to something that is similar in structure to the input I've shown below.

```
Input = [ 
    { "Hotel": "California" }, 
    { "Floor": "2" }, 
    { "Number of Rooms": "25" }, 
    { "Floor": "3" }, 
    { "Number of Rooms": "42" }, 
    { "Hotel": "Marigold" }, 
    { "Floor": "2" }, 
    { "Number of Rooms": "5" }, 
    { "Hotel": "Notel" }, 
    { "Floor": "" }, 
    { "Number of Rooms": "" } 
]

Output = [ 
    { "Hotel": "California", "Floor": "2", "Number of Rooms": "25" },
    { "Hotel": "California", "Floor": "3", "Number of Rooms": "42" }, 
    { "Hotel": "Marigold", "Floor": "2", "Number of Rooms": "5" }, 
    { "Hotel": "Notel", "Floor": "", "Number of Rooms": "" }
]
```

Comment: The only thing that links the hotel, the floor and the number of rooms together is the order of that input?

Comment: @pandaadb yes that is correct

Comment: There is no way of doing this via the aggregation as far as I know. I would recommend restructuring your data in the correct form and storing it in your database rather than making use of aggregation here.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the data as is from the database. Perform all the tabular conversion on the server side.

Do not mess aggregation framework with the business logic.

Eventually less networking from db to the server and more testable.